# ¿como almacenar un archivo pdf en la carpeta download?

Tags: android, android-studio, itext

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

He realizado un ejemplo de crear un archivo pdf usando IText 7 en android studio y funciona a la perfección.

Lo que deseo es como guardarlo en la carpeta descargas(download) de mi dispositivo.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btnGuardarPDF;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnGuardarPDF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuardarPDF);
        btnGuardarPDF.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            crearPDF();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void crearPDF() throws IOException {

        File pdfFile;
        File docFolder = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"");
        if(!docFolder.exists()){
            docFolder.mkdir();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        String pdfname = "GiftItem.pdf";
        pdfFile = new File(docFolder.getAbsolutePath(),pdfname);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
        PdfWriter pw = new PdfWriter(output);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pw);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument,PageSize.LETTER);
        document.setMargins(75,35,70,35);

        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD);

        Table tablaTitulo = new Table(1).useAllAvailableWidth();
        Cell cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("EJEMPLO IMPLEMENTANDO ITEXT")).setFontSize(14).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).setFont(font);
        tablaTitulo.addCell(cell);

        document.add(tablaTitulo);
        document.close();
        Toast.makeText(this,"PDF Creado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la referencia al directorio "/Dowloads" que puedes obtener mediante:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

de esta forma:

```
  pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),pdfname);
```